# Is there a way to get the column names from a SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, relation

I'm using Dapper and I want to get all the column names from a SQL statement that is provided at runtime. It should not matter if the resulting relation, returned from the database, is empty or not.

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetColumnsFromSQLStatement(string sqlStatement)
{
    List<string> Columns = new List<string>();

    using (var con = SourceDatabaseConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
    {
        using (var dbTrans = SourceTransactionFactory.CreateTransaction(con, TransactionOptions.ReadOnly))
        {
            DynamicParameters para = new DynamicParameters();

            var tmp = con.QueryAsync(sqlStatement, para, dbTrans,  100,  CommandType.Text);
            /*build the column string list?*/

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
    }

    return Columns;
}
```

I expect that I can provide a string list with the column names.

Comment: Note: passing in just a `string` (without args) here makes me worry that you're exposing yourself to SQL injection risks.

Answer (score 1):

When using the non-generic `Query[Async]` API, each row can be cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` which provides access to the names. Alternatively, use the API that returns a data-reader.

Comment: doesn't work with my firebird connection: var tmp = con.ExecuteReader(sqlStatement, para, dbTrans, 100, CommandType.Text);

                    var tmp2 = tmp.GetSchemaTable().Columns;
                    
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in tmp2)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName);
                    }

Comment: Do you have maybe a example?

Comment: @RHofmann Data reader has a direct API to get column names - something like GetName(int) (I'm not at a PC to check)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to get the column names without having any record in the resulting relation from the sql statment:

```
 public async Task<List<string>> GetColumnsFromSQLStatement(string sqlStatement)
    {
        List<string> Columns = new List<string>();

        using (var con = SourceDatabaseConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var dbTrans = SourceTransactionFactory.CreateTransaction(con, TransactionOptions.ReadOnly))
            {
                DynamicParameters para = new DynamicParameters();

                var tmp = con.ExecuteReader(sqlStatement, para, dbTrans, 100, CommandType.Text);
                var schema = tmp.GetSchemaTable();
                for (var i = 0; i < schema.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Columns.Add(schema.Rows[i]["columnName"].ToString());
                }
                dbTrans.Commit();
            }
        }

        return Columns;
    }
```

So you it is possible to build complex statements with e.g. stored produceders and functions.